# Correct way to write a sub-query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-server-2014

I'm reviewing an existing stored procedure in our environment and I've run across a subquery inside a stored procedure that I do not believe is correct - but I don't have that much experience with subqueries.

According to this Technet article, a subquery is also called an inner query or inner select, while the statement containing a subquery is also called an outer query or outer select.  [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY c.socialSecurityNumber ) AS [SSNRanking] ,
   c.socialSecurityNumber AS [SSN] ,
   c.id AS [CustomerID] ,
   c2.socialSecurityNumber AS [DupSSN] ,
   c2.id AS [DupCustomerID]
FROM   dbo.Customers AS [c]
   INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS [c2] ON c.socialSecurityNumber = c2.socialSecurityNumber AND c.id <> c2.id
WHERE  c.id NOT IN (   SELECT mergedTo
                       FROM   Customers
                       WHERE  customerStatusTypeID = 'M'
                              AND isMerged = 1
                              AND mergedTo IS NOT NULL
                   )
```

If the subquery is like a JOIN, then joining on c.id to the mergedto field makes no sense and I think must be an error.

In reality, the code should be written:

```
c.id NOT IN ( SELECT id from dbo.Customers...)
```

to ensure the correct records are returned.  Isn't that how a subquery should work?

Comment: depends whether the person designing your db tried to store id in mergedto

Comment: Understood. Thanks for that insight.  It really did help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the query is trying to do here is to get only those records for customers which haven not been merged to different customer id. It appears that in your table, at different times, you are assigning different id to same person, same social security number. That is why, query is picking up records of the customer id

1. Who have same social security number, that means it is the same person.
2. Then, filtering the records to get only those records which have not been merged into a different customer id.

So,  that means query is trying to get current customer id of the customer, and only that record which has not been merged to different customer id, against the social security number.